# TextInputLayout could not be instantiated

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I was working with TextInputLayout and it is showing me following error :

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

Preview of the layout is not appearing.

I looked in to the code of TextInputLayout but I found nothing to fix, here is my code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/angleMesurementTool"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ifsloppedRoof"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                >

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/angleMesurementToolINput"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="aaa ssddf swery asd w"
                    android:text=""
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_13"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/buildingAgeInput"
                />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

But when I remove one character (w) from hint then it works and preview also appears.

I am not getting what wrong is happening when I increase characters after a length.

Answer (score 0):

> Try with this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/angleMesurementTool"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ifsloppedRoof"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/angleMesurementToolINput"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="aaa ssddf swery asd w"
                    android:text=""
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_13"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/buildingAgeInput"
                />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```